# Get value of cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for help on the following :

[Exemple sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Anp_MckB6OksdDEzQkhzNWMxNDN5aXNPOGQzRzNPa0E#gid=0)

I need the word Frisbee to be put in the green cell

Any idea ?

The value researched will always be text, and depending on a date.

Edit :
Just made the spreadsheet public and open to comments, sorry.

I have a column C with items acquired and a column B with the date of the acquisition. It's not sorted by date, so I first have to acquire the most recent date (with =TO_DATE(MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B9))) ), then I need to get the content of the cell that is corresponding to the date (on the same line, separated horizontally by one or more cell).

Comment: Could you expand your question to include some example cells, illustrating your problem? If the spreadsheet you link to should go away some day, the question will be useless. We like to keep as much information as possible within the actual question. Also, the spreadsheet you're linking to requires access. Did you make it public?

Comment: Done, hope all the information needed is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following formula to get the "frisbee".

### Formula

```
=QUERY(B3:C8; "SELECT C ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 1")
```

### Explained

The `QUERY` will take both columns as dataset, but it will only show column C. Furthermore, it will sort column B descendingly (highest first) and the limit option will limit the result dataset to one row.

In this case, there's no need to calculate the highest date first.

### Example

I've copied your file and added my solution: **[FRISBEE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At3L7K_lcLHydC1hQkQ0WEdwX2ZDWWF3YlNaOVdPdmc&usp=sharing)**